# Como montar um select pegando informações do banco de dados

Tags: php, html5, mysqli, html-select

Gostaria de montar um `select` com informações do banco de dados utilizando *Mysqli*, sendo que o `value`, vai receber informações do meu `cod_usuario` e a informação que será exibida é a coluna `nome`.

```
<select>
  <option name="nome_tecnico" value="
      <?php
        $query = $con->query("SELECT cod_usuario FROM pv_usuario where cod_cargo = 1 and ativo = 1");
        while($reg = $query->fetch_array()) {
          echo $reg["cod_usuario"];
        }
      ?>
    ">
    <?php 
      $query = $con->query("SELECT nome FROM pv_usuario where cod_cargo = 1 and ativo = 1");
      while($reg = $query->fetch_array()) {
        echo $reg["nome"];
      }
    ?>
  </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fica tipo assim

```
<select name="xpto">
<?php
   $query = $con->query("SELECT cod_usuario FROM pv_usuario where cod_cargo = 1 and ativo = 1");
      while($reg = $query->fetch_array())
      {
          echo '<option value="'.$reg["cod_usuario"].'">'.$reg["nome"].'</option>';    
      }
?>    
</select>
```

Comment: Correção: Select cod_usuario, nome

Comment: perfeito tinha esquecido disso

Comment: Eu percebi.
Obrigado.
Vou testar agora.

Comment: Oi,  @JoaoPaulo  . 
Não retornou nada. Sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: Desculpa.
Funcionou.

Comment: então marca como resolvido e da um plus ai

Answer (score 1):

A tag [select](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) utiliza a tag [option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option) para exibir uma opção selecionável. Dê uma olhada nesse exemplo:

```
<select>
    <option value="1">Opção 1</option>
    <option value="2">Opção 2</option>
    <option value="3">Opção 3</option>
</select>
```

Cada tag `<option>` representa uma opção selecionável.
Com isso, é necessário percorrer cada registro retornado do banco de dados e criar uma tag `<option>` para cada um deles.

Acredito que isso deva funcionar:

```
<?php $query = $con->query("SELECT cod_usuario, nome FROM pv_usuario where cod_cargo = 1 and ativo = 1"); ?>

<select>
    <?php while($reg = $query->fetch_array()) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $reg['cod_usuario']; ?>">
            <?php echo $reg['nome']; ?>
        </option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```